# Adding custom event triggers to YTPlayer for iOS

Tags: ios, youtube-api

I have embedded the YouTube in my application now all I want is to bind the fullscreen button of the player to my custom method in iOS, Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: have you tried any method??

Comment: I can not find any thing related to this.

Comment: Would the [iOS YouTube Helper](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/ios_youtube_helper) handle what you intend to develop? It seems to use the same function with the JS so you'll just have to set `playsinline` to `0` in your custom iOS method.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `UIWindowDidBecomeHiddenNotification` and `UIWindowDidBecomeVisibleNotification` notifications.  When the full screen player opens, it hides the application's window.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(videoExitFullScreen:)
                                                 name:UIWindowDidBecomeVisibleNotification
                                               object:self.view.window];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(videoEnterFullScreen:)
                                                 name:UIWindowDidBecomeHiddenNotification
                                               object:self.view.window];
```

Related discussion on the [youtube-ios-player-helper GitHub issues page](https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=UIWindowDidBecomeHiddenNotification).